Finding a function through equation
Let f be a real valued continuous function such that $f(x^2)=(f(x))^2$ for all $x$ in the domain.
We have to prove the following:
A) There is a unique function defined on $(0,1)$ such that $f(0)\neq0$
B)There are infinitely many functions $f$ with domain $(0,\infty)$ such that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}{f(x) \, dx}<1$
Any hints would be helpful

A) given continuous $f({x}^2)={f(x)}^2$ for all $x \in (0,1)$
And $f(0) \neq 0$
Claims:
(1.1): $f(0)=1$
(1.2): $f(x) = 1$ is the unique solution.
Proof(1.1):
Plug $ x=0:$
$$f(0)=f(0)^2$$
Since $f(0) \neq 0$, divide both side by $f(0)$:
$$f(0)=1$$
Proof(1.2):
By contradiction, assuming there exists $s \in (0,1)$ such that $f(s)=y \neq 1$
If $y=-1$, by the intermediate value theorem, $f(0)=1$ and $f(s)=-1$, there exists $t \in (0,s)$ such that $f(t)=0 \neq 1.$ Therefore, WLOG, assume $y \neq -1$
$$ {f(s)}^2={y}^2= f({s}^2)$$
$$ {f({s}^2)}^2={y}^4= f({s}^4)$$
$$ {f({s}^4)}^2={y}^8= f({s}^8)$$
It is easy to show that ${y}^n= f({s}^n)$ for all $n=2^k$ where $k$ is a positive integer.
Take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, ${s}^n \rightarrow 0$
By the continuity,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(s^n)= f(0)=  \lim_{n\to\infty} y^n $$
By (1.1), $f(0)=1$, which means $|y|=1$.However, $y \neq 1$ and $y \neq -1$. We reached a contradiction.
B) given real valued continuous $f(x)$ such that $f({x}^2)={f(x)}^2$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}{f(x) \, dx}<1$
Considering
$$f(x)=x^r$$
Noticed that $1^{r}=1$ for all real numbers $r$
So, define
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        x^{r_1} & \text{if } x <1\\
        x^{r_2} & \text{if } x\geq 1\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
It is easy to see $f(x)$ is continuous.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{f(x) \, dx}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}{f(x) \, dx}+ \int_{1}^{\infty}{f(x) \, dx} $$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}{x^{r_1} \, dx}+ \int_{1}^{\infty}{x^{r_2} \, dx} $$
$$= \frac{x^{r_1+1}}{r_1+1}\Big|_0^1 +\frac{x^{r_2+1}}{r_2+1} \Big|_1^\infty$$
We got two assumptions: $r_1+1>0$, $r_2+1<0$ and the inequity: $\frac{1}{r_1+1}-\frac{1}{r_2+1}<1$
Take $r_1>1,r_2<-3$ , clearly there is infinitely many combinations of them, and all those satisfies the criteria. Therefore, we have found infinitely many solutions to this functional equation.

Thank you, I was wondering if there is an elementary method to this, as it is from a high school test, and participants are required to do in in 2-3 minutes

@Someone An elementary method would be, only power functions are likely to satisfy the requirements. Based on this assumption, you can immediately prove both (A) and (B) in a not rigorous manner.
